# Capture group in Lua pattern matches literal digit character instead of capture group

Tags: lua, string-matching, lua-patterns

I want to extract the VALUE of lines containing `key="VALUE"`, and I am trying to use a simple Lua pattern to solve this.

It works for lines except for those which contains a literal `1` in the VALUE. It seems the pattern parser is confusing my capture group for an escape sequence.

```
> return  string.find('... key = "PHONE2" ...', 'key%s*=%s*(["\'])([^%1]-)%1')
5       18      "       PHONE2
> return  string.find('... key = "PHONE1" ...', 'key%s*=%s*(["\'])([^%1]-)%1')
nil
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use the `[^%1]` at all. Just use `.-` as it, by definition, matches the smallest possible string.

Also, you can use multiline string syntax, to not have to escape the quotes in your pattern:

```
> s=[[... key = "PHONE1" ...]]
> return s:find [[key%s*=%s*(["'])(.-)%1]]
5       18      "       PHONE1
```

---

The pattern `[^%1]` actually means, do not search for characters `%` and `1` individually.

Comment: Thanks. I find out as well that I would escape the 1 to force it to include the capture group in the set. `[^%\1]`
Your solution makes more sense and is cleaner. I will use it.

Comment: @nolan In that case, you just want to use `[^\1]`. The `%` character is not required.

Comment: Indeed it is not. Thank you.